# General Solution of sin(2x)-cos(2x)=0

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find the general solution to the equation sin(2x)-cos(2x)=0

Comment: Welcome to the math.SE. Do you have tried to solve himself this exercise? Surely it's no good to have answers if you haven't tried to solve goniometric equations yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\sin(\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ when $\theta=\dfrac{\pi}4+{n\pi}.$

Now solve $2x=\theta.$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use that $$\sin(x)-\cos(y)=-2 \sin \left(-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right) \sin
   \left(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $\sin(2x)=\cos(2x)$, then $\tan(2x)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin2x=\cos2x$$

$$\tan2x=\dfrac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}=1=\tan\dfrac\pi4$$

Alternatively $$cos2x=\sin2x=\cos(\pi/2-2x)$$